# Can we really fill anything we want in transition-property CSS?

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I just realized we can put any kind of value we want behind `transition-property` CSS parameter, because I just did it (not on purpose). Then I went to [see the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property) and they we can fill any custom-value :

```
/* <custom-ident> values */
transition-property: test_05;
transition-property: -specific;
transition-property: sliding-vertically;

/* Multiple values */
transition-property: test1, animation4;
transition-property: all, height, all;
transition-property: all, -moz-specific, sliding;
```

So I am wondering : as  neither `test1` nor `animation4` is a valid CSS property, what kind of values, if it is not a property, can be passed in `transition-property` ? A keyframe ? what else ?

[EDIT]: I added the example given by MDN for multiple values, where some `transition-property` aren't filled with valid CSS properties.

Comment: From the same article - [set of properties that can be animated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)

Comment: and if you click on custom indent you can continue reading and understand https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/custom-ident .. don't stop at half the road follow all the links ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we continue reading you can see the different values as follow:

> **none**
>
> No properties will transition.
>
> **all**
>
> All properties that can transition will.
>
> `<custom-ident>`
>
> **A string identifying the property** to which a transition effect should be applied when its value changes.

So yes you can put what you want here and the idea behind `<custom-indent>` is to avoid specifing an exhaustive list of all the available properties. So if in the future a new property is added, this will remain valid and we don't have to change it.

And if you put something like `random_58468` it will be a valid value and you won't get a warning but of course nothing will happen since there is no property called `random_58468`.

Comment: yeah but just byon it is also written: `transition-property: test1, animation4; transition-property: all, height, all; transition-property: all, -moz-specific, sliding;`
`test1` and `animation4` aren't a property, why did MDN give that example too ?

Comment: @arnaudambro exactly like I told :) you can put what you want, transition doesn't care about it .. all of them are valid, but you will simply have no effect.

Comment: alright then, I think it's weird from MDN to put some values that have no effect without saying it out loud ! Thanks @TemaniAfif